# How does a Python object become a raw type

Tags: python, cython, ctypes, pack

I'm trying to speed up `struct.pack()`, and feel like I'm missing something fundamental in the act of getting raw values out of Python objects.

Let's say I wrote the fastest C / cython module that takes a list of Python ints -

`[1, 14, 78, -789... ]`

and packs them into a buffer. Then let's say I use it from Python using ctypes / cython respectively.

I still had to pass a Python list to a C module, so somewhere there, Python already had the actual ints available in their raw form, 4 bytes each.

So it seems like by the time those ints "hit" the C module, I already did what I came to do, I just don't have it in my hands.

Where does that conversion happen? Can I somehow plug into that process from pure Python? I know of `to_bytes()`, but it's even slower than `struct.pack()` so it can't be that.

Comment: the list hits C code in the form of a pointer to a [`PyObject`](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html) it's not getting serialised to a packed array of ints anywhere

Comment: Can I address the PyObject myself somehow, and get the int bytes out of it?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding how CPython works, it's `PyObject`s all the way down.  an "int" is 28 bytes and `list`s are just an array of pointers to these objects

Comment: So I can't get "inside" a `PyObject` from within Python? Even with something like the `ast` module or `ctypes.py_object()`?

Comment: `ast` is syntax, not internal representation... if you don't care about big-ints you could maybe use numpy to serialise things for you, it should be pretty quick.  I'd suggest reading through the link in my first comment though

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html Here's the documentation for how you'd do it in C. It's worth pointing out what a Python integer can be arbitrarily large (and a C one can't) so you can't directly extract it - youhave to do some processing to make sure it doesn't overflow.